# When does it have 'so' in a pronoun or an adjective?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I have read all the versions but not sure when to use what?

> Whatever - Whatsoever; 
>   Whoever - Whosoever.

When does it take ***'so'***

Also, the word *so* is conjunction here or something else?

Comment: No.  *Whatsoever* and *whosoever* are single words, so the *so* they contain is not a conjunction or even a word.  As it happens, *whatsoever* is relatively common, while *whosoever* is rather archaic and only appears in very formal registers.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same and used as a intensifier. But the two aren't always interchangeable. As usual, context is all-important. For example:

> I want nothing whatever to do with your half-baked plans.
>
> I want nothing whatsoever to do with your half-baked plans.

The link below might help you.

[Use of “whatever” vs “whatsoever”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70234/use-of-whatever-vs-whatsoever)

Comment: Are both those examples correct? Or is one of them wrong?

Comment: They are interchangeable in this context. The are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation seems to be that the words **what** and **ever** can be joined to make **whatever**, and it looks like you might be thinking that one of those words then modifies (takes) the other when they appear together. Even if that's not what you're thinking, lets discuss it first to clarify it for others.

## You can't just join English words and have them make sense

In English, "joining" one word to another (where it looks like there is a larger word made up of smaller words) doesn't necessarily mean anything. For example, it is okay to say "I am **up to** no good", but in the sentence "I am **upto** no good", **upto** is not an English word. Similarly, "We are going **together**" has a totally separate meaning than "We are going **to get her**".

Sometimes there are words that modify each other or are otherwise meaningful when put together, but the only example that comes to mind is that "**in to**" and "**into**" usually mean the same thing. Unfortunately the same cannot always be said for "**up on**" and "**upon**", where the sentence "We went **up on** the mountain" definitely has meaning, and the sentence "We went **upon** the mountain" is ambiguous and maybe even raunchy…. (There are [prefixes and suffixes](http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php) in English, but rarely can a prefix/suffix be used as a word on its own. And those are a completely separate topic anyway.)

## So what do those words mean?

When you understand the first part, you realize that each of these words are totally separate, each with separate definitions and uses, upon which the word "**so**" has no bearing, so let's define them online.

- **[whatever](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+whatever)**
- **[whatsoever](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+whatsoever)**
- **[whoever](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+whoever)**
- **[whosoever](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+whosoever)**